# How to define the width limit which defines whether or not to display an hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,

I was inspired by a youtube tutorial to create a hamburger menu. When I resize my PC browser window to a given width, the hamburger menu appears and everything is working absolutely fine, as you can see in this first screenshot:

[image]

The only problem I'm facing is when I try to call the same page using my Android (Samsung Galaxy S20) smartphone, the "classic" menu bar appears.

[image]

Do you think I need to add a function which would be smartphone specific, so I could have the same hamburger menu on my smartphone as on the first picture?

I don't know whether it could be helpful - most importantly, I don't know where to start to investigate - but I'm enclosing my html, css and javascript files.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css?rnd=999" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/menu.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="branding">
          <h2><a href="#" class="branding-logo">Welcome</a></h2>
        </div>
        <label for="input-hamburger" class="hamburger "></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input-hamburger" hidden>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>

          <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">Services
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Web Design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Web Development</a></li>
              <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Full Stack Development
                  <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Wordpress Development</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Front End Development</a></li>
                  <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-link">MEAN Stack Development
                      <span class="arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">MongoDb</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">ExpressJS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">AngularJS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">NodeJS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Back End Development</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">UI/UX Design</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Articles</a></li>

          <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my css code (mystyle.css) that my html code is referring to :

```
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  --primary: #e70146;
  --hover-color: #fdd052;
  --dark: #1c2022;
  --light: #fff;

  --header-bg: var(--primary);
}
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "josefin sans", "helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

header {
  background: var(--header-bg);
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.branding-logo {
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: calc(0.8rem + 1vw);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--light);
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* Styling submenu */
.has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  min-width: 16em;

  /* hide submenus */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
.submenu > li > a {
  padding: 0.8em 1.5em;
}
.submenu .submenu {
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
}
.submenu .submenu .submenu {
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
}

.menu > li:hover > a,
.submenu > li:hover > a {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.05);
  color: var(--hover-color);
}
.menu > li:hover > a {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.95);
}

/* Arrows */

.arrow {
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 0.15em solid currentColor;
  border-bottom: 0.15em solid currentColor;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-top: -0.25em;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Reveal  */
.menu > li:hover > a + .submenu,
.submenu > li:hover > a + .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

/* ANIMATE aRROWS */
.menu > li:hover > a > .arrow,
.submenu > li:hover > a > .arrow {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 78.75em) {
  .submenu .submenu .submenu {
    left: -100%;
    top: 0.5em;
  }
  .submenu {
    min-width: 16em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 58.75em) {
  .menu li a {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
/*     position: relative; */
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
  }
  .menu {
    flex-flow: column;
    position: absolute;
    background: var(--light);
    top: 4.55em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;

    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top center;
    transition: 200ms transform cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.4, 0.42, 1.48) 100ms,
      100ms opacity ease-in-out;
    
    overflow-y: scroll;
    
  }
  .menu > li > a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--dark);
  }
  .submenu > li > a {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .submenu {
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    border-left: 0.12em dotted hsla(342, 99%, 45%, 0.95);
  }
  .submenu .submenu {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .submenu .submenu .submenu {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .menu > li:hover > a + .submenu,
  .submenu > li:hover > a + .submenu {
    position: relative;
  }

  .hamburger {
    width: 2em;
    height: 0.25em;
    display: block;
    background: var(--light);
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in-out;
  }
  .hamburger::after,
  .hamburger::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;

    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in-out;
  }

  .hamburger::after {
    top: 0.65em;
  }
  .hamburger::before {
    bottom: 0.65em;
  }

  .close::after,
  .close::before {
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in-out;
  }
  .close::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .close {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in-out;
  }
  .close::after {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  /* reveal menu */
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .menu {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

main {
/* just to make scrollable vertically to see sticky navbar    */
  height: 200vh;
}
```

Here is my javascript code (menu.js) that my html is referring to:

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.classList.toggle("close");
});
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Maybe this will help `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in head tag

Comment: Thank you very much Ashishmaurya. Enjoy your week-end and take care.

Comment: Is  your problem solved? If not, you might try setting widths in px rather than em and see what happens .

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY THIS:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
<link
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
rel="stylesheet"
/>
<!-- MDB -->
<link
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css"
rel="stylesheet"
/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
            data-mdb-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent3" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent3"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent3">
        <div class="bg-light shadow-3 p-4">
          <button class="btn btn-link btn-block border-bottom m-0">Link 1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-link btn-block border-bottom m-0">Link 2</button>
          <button class="btn btn-link btn-block m-0">Link 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- MDB -->
<script
type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.js"
></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed to add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

It is necessary to add "viewport" to tell the browser to render pages according to the width of the device.